# How to monopolize a GPU after submitting a job in slurm on a cluster

Tags: gpu, nvidia, jobs, slurm, sbatch

I have used the instructions such as 'nvidia-smi -c 3' or 'nvidia-smi -i  0  -c 3'. But they seem have no effect.

The following is my script in slurm. But the GPU my job runs on is still shared with other people.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o job.%j.out
#SBATCH --partition=GPU3
#SBATCH --qos=low
#SBATCH -J job1
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --time=300

nvidia-smi -c 3 
python abc.py
```

How to monopolize a GPU after submitting a job?